# Do all blocks that end up in the main chain pass through handle_block_to_main_chain at some point?

Tags: blockchain

Do all blocks that end up in the main chain pass through handle_block_to_main_chain at some point (even during reorgs?)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/fd3b71129b43fc86e5830b62b0f1dbc5ede63c5e/src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp), yes.

Answer (score 0):

In most situations, yes. The one exception is when running `monero-blockchain-import` with verification turned off (which is why people recommending doing this with a file downloaded from the internet are mean and out to get you).

Comment: You sure about this? Looking at the code, blocks eventually go through `Blockchain::add_new_block` which does go through `handle_block_to_main_chain`.

Comment: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/b780cf4db1f9dfc49e7f16afc47892a5b40fe68a/src/blockchain_utilities/blockchain_import.cpp#L217 reaches https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/fd3b71129b43fc86e5830b62b0f1dbc5ede63c5e/src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp#L3721 which reaches https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/fd3b71129b43fc86e5830b62b0f1dbc5ede63c5e/src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp#L3353